# Upload Video with Android Intent Crashes

Tags: android, video, upload, android-intent

I have an app that creates a video in WebM format.  I want to use an Android `intent` to send this video to Youtube, facebook, etc.

I have code that creates an intent and starts a chooser where I can pick where to upload to, after selecting the destination and filling in the form with title etc. I hit the Upload button and the app I am trying to upload with crashes immediately.

Here is my relevant code:

```
    Uri videoURI = Uri.fromFile(new File( pathName + fileName));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("video/webm");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoURI);
    try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Upload video via:"));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e("MWR", "No Way to Share!");
    }
```

pathName + fileName is the absolute path of the video on the SD card.

Here is the relevant log info for a Youtube Crash

```
11-02 13:42:43.949: WARN/dalvikvm(4443): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1325)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:536)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.youtube.YouTubeSettingsActivity.a(SourceFile:183)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.SettingsActivity.b(SourceFile:43)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.j.run(SourceFile:348)
11-02 13:42:43.949: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4443):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-02 13:42:43.956: WARN/ActivityManager(2494):   Force finishing activity com.google.android.apps.uploader/.clients.youtube.YouTubeSettingsActivity
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443): Activity com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.youtube.YouTubeSettingsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40553f20 that was originally added here
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.youtube.YouTubeSettingsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40553f20 that was originally added here
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.SettingsActivity.b(SourceFile:43)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at com.google.android.apps.uploader.clients.c.onClick(SourceFile:122)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-02 13:42:44.261: ERROR/WindowManager(4443):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is the relevant log for a Facebook crash:

```
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.facebook.katana.service.FacebookService@4068d4f8 with Intent { cmp=com.facebook.katana/.service.FacebookService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2128)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:124)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1031)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at com.facebook.katana.service.method.VideoUpload.getRealPathFromURI(VideoUpload.java:127)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at com.facebook.katana.service.method.VideoUpload.start(VideoUpload.java:148)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at com.facebook.katana.service.FacebookService.startOp(FacebookService.java:1250)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at com.facebook.katana.service.FacebookService.onStart(FacebookService.java:742)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:428)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2115)
 11-02 13:57:40.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4497):     ... 10 more
```

So, an update:

The `URI` was preventing it from starting the process. 
I found another post on how to create a `URI` with `ContentResolver` and this fixed the issue.
However, it doesn't get past 0% and says my video is 0 Bytes but I believe this may be an issue with my video creation.

Comment: Post the stack trace from your log output when the app crashes

Comment: Do you have a separate thread running to handle the uploading process? if not this should be done so you do not interfere with the main UI thread. Otherwise you can get timeout crashes if the process is blocking the ui thread for too long.

Comment: what device are you testing this on? some devices (like the DroidX) disable your SDCard when you're tethered via USB, so, you'd never get past the first line, here.

Comment: It's crashing because it's looking for the date and time the video was created. The approach in this post works well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884092/android-youtube-upload-using-intent/6482526#comment10452237_6482526 (see my recent comment there about also specifying the size)