# Uploading a YouTube video from an Android application

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I have a doubt about the ability to integrate youtube to my mobile application.
The mobile application should have a button for loading (by the user) video directly on youtube, on a dedicated channel. This channel will be created from my client. There is the possibility, through the bees, to integrate video upload directly to a specific youtube channel?

it's for android application.

Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to upload a video to YouTube in an Android application is to use the `Intent` exposed by the YouTube application. There's examples of doing this in other Stack Overflow questions, e.g. [android youtube upload using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884092/android-youtube-upload-using-intent)

That being said, I wanted to point out that uploading videos into a single "master" account (which you seem to want to do, based on your question) isn't a good idea. This blog post explains why that is in more detail: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html