# How to upload video to youtube in android?

Tags: android, video, upload, youtube-api, share

I am Creating an application which records video and uploads it on YouTube and others Social sites.

For upload I use Droid share functionality and it works good.

In e-mail, Facebook, Skype, etc upload works perfect, but when I select YouTube, it does not upload my video.

Here is the code I use for video sharing.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"SUBJECT_NAME");
sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
File newFile = new File(video_path);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(newFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Where you want to share?"));
```

Comment: I also face that problem and i tried to found lots but not get any perfect solution.

Comment: I try to found the solution and some times get good results but not for droid share its with the google api to use particular youtube share only.

Comment: I really like to sow this question because if this question gets perfect answer then i need to use.

Comment: try to build the URI as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884092/android-youtube-upload-using-intent/6482526#comment10452237_6482526

Comment: Can I get a link of shared video?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this code.

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "video_path");
ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"share:"));
```

this code is *add* in your **share button's onClick()** *method* and get result.
pass the value in **EXTRA_STREAM** as an **URI** not as file.

Comment: @Sandip Chaniyara thanks to use this code... I also implement this.

Comment: awsome thanks... for internal storage you can use INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Comment: I only get "No apps can perform this action", why?

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I lost an hour or so trying to get user2126788's code to work because I forgot to set the type on the intent.

```
sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
```

Answer (score 1):

please add this line in android manifest

```
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
     <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" /> 
     </intent-filter>
```

Comment: put it in Activity which is used for video share. and just put it in manifest file but not change anything else?

Comment: I put it but not works, same problem it is redirect to activity. any other changes required with this code?

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of trying to find out how to make it work for uploading and sharing video on facebook, youtube, instagram and whatsapp. this is the code that worked for  me.
Uploading recorded video from your application to social media applications

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
            content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "your_path_to_video");
            ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"share:"));
```

Comment: Great answer @Tarek Mowafy . But can i am getting the title and description empty in the youtube upload page.

Comment: @David , i am sorry for the late reply , i am sorry again but i cannot get your question , when you are uploading a video to youtube you have to select a title and a description for the video, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me fine.

I try to Implement and get best result.

so,if anyone face this type of problem try this code.

I'm sure It's also works perfect for you.

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "path_of_video");
ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title_text");
//sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
//File newFile = new File(path_var);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Where you want to share?"));
```

this code is pitting in your share button's onClick() method and get result.

Answer (score 0):

This code is *working for me fine.*

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title_text");
//sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
File newFile = new File(path_var);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Where you want to share?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution is to implement your own upload mechanism without leaving your app.
You can use Google Java and Android libraries with YouTube java libraries.

Here's a full app utilizing this: https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android

Answer (score 0):

```
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, path);
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri1 =  Uri.fromFile(new File(path)); 

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
        sharingIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Title");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Desc");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri1);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share to"));
```