# Share video and save video to Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I have video url, from which I parse to to get the uri. I try to pass the uri in share, but I don't see the video being shared.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri
                               );
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Am I missing something here, or should I save the uri to external storage and then pass it?

Also I need to know how to save the video using the uri to Gallery.

Comment: Any answers or suggestions?

Comment: any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("video/mp4");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share"));
```

"path" is your videos pass like /sdcard/mVideo.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Intent.createChooser seems to be missing. Please see the code snippet and the link.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

The link:
http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am able to see the list of options to send, like Facebook, GMAIL etc. When I select GMAIL, I see the email is sent with no video attached.

Comment: I meant without your answer I am able to see the list of options. My main issue is that the video is not getting sent. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I tried something similar. It worked - received the video file as an email attachment.

You might want to check the size of the video file.

Also, pls have a look the below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965246/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-in-android

The type needs to be:

sharingIntent.setType("video/*");