# How to upload video to youtube in android using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video, upload, youtube

I am uploading video to youtube via share button. If I click upload button, it shows the social icon like whatsapp,facebook,youtube. When I click youtube it should be uploaded to youtube.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_FILE1 = 1;
private static final int SELECT_FILE2 = 2;
String selectedPath1 = "NONE";
String selectedPath2 = "NONE";
TextView tv, res;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Button b1,b3;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + selectedPath1);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
        }
    });

    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

             doFileUpload();
        }
    });

}

public void openGallery(int req_code){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/* video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
  }

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1)
        {
            selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("selectedPath1 : " + selectedPath1);
        }

        tv.setText("Selected File paths : " + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private void doFileUpload()
{

    //File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("video/mp4");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedPath1);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Upload video via:"));  

}


}
```

After I selected Video, I can select youtube icon. Then youtube window is closed automatically. Any suggestion is highly appreciable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "video_path");
ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"share:"));
```

[How to upload video to youtube in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965246/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-in-android?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks Miki When use this code i getting error..please find the error log.

Comment: you should to add this permission:  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Thanks Miki I added in manifest that permission now i am getting like NO APPS Can perform This Action

Comment: Great answer @MikiFranko . But can i fill the title and description in the youtube upload page using intent.

Comment: I only get "No apps can perform this action", why?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("video/mp4");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title_text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,selectedImageUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Upload video via:"));
```