# How to upload video on youtube with title and description

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

How to upload video with title and description via intent.I tried via Intent from this example [How to upload video to youtube in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965246/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-in-android) but I can set just a video.How to set also title and descriptions to video?Thanks.

Here is peace of my code

```
 Video videoForShare = mListVideos.get(position);

            ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoForShare.getVideoName());
            ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

            if (uri == null)
                uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Upload video via: "));
```

Comment: Please share the code what you have done with the intent so we can correct you.