# choose video from gallery and upload on installed youtube app

Tags: android, video, upload, youtube

i want to build an app that allows user to choose video from gallery and when the user picks the video it starts uploading on the youtube app installed on phone. the youtube app installed on phone is already signed in. so far i have been able to only open the app on picking the video, please help me further.

```
package com.PG.video;

   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.
   import android.os.Build;



   import java.io.File;




import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button camerabtn;
Button upld;
public static final int request_Code = 0;
EditText et;
private static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    camerabtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    upld=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    camerabtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            File mediaFile =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                       + "/"+et.getText().toString()+".mp4");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

                Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }}
        );


    upld.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            String value = null;
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, value);
            startActivityForResult(intent, request_Code);



        }
    });

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
    case VIDEO_CAPTURE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                       data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording cancelled.", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to record video", 
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
             break;

    case request_Code:
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
        break;
    }

                }
    }
```

Comment: I think this link will help you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884092/android-youtube-upload-using-intent)

Comment: thankyou vivek i was able to open youtube app upload page but it closes within seconds, please help.                              selectedVideoPath = getPath(data.getData());
   Intent intent = new Intent();

   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.setType("video/3gpp");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedVideoPath);
   
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "upload via"));

Comment: I think 3gpp videos is not supported. Try to upload mp4 videos.. Try this link also.. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965246/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-in-android)

Comment: still not working. i was uploading mp4 videos but youtube app upload page    closes within 2 seconds. does it require youtube api access?